# Meaning of "emphasis" in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I have a problem with this sentence:

> **If the world was dominated by emphasis, the Monarchy preferred discretion, restrained passions, a calm tone of voice.**

I can't get the first part. What is the meaning of **"emphasis"** here? And
what is the meaning of **"If the world was [were?] dominated by emphasis"?**

In order to get a proper answer, I think this question needs more explanation, therefore I decided to write the whole paragraph here. It is about Joseph Roth, a great Austrian writer of Galician descent, and his good experience in his Austro-Hungarian fatherland. He says:

> Everything in this world was continuously in a state of constant
>   change: familiar and strange, quotidian and remarkable, ‘that, which
>   was strange, became familiar, without losing its colours, and the
>   homeland had the pleasing charm of abroad’ [ . . . ] It was thus a
>   cheerful and bright place, downright innocent [ . . . ] If the world
>   was dominated by emphasis, the Monarchy preferred discretion,
>   restrained passions, a calm tone of voice. It was often irresistibly
>   funny, very much like an operetta put on by third-rate actors.

Comment: I think your question boils down to a poor translation. Roth is one of my favorite authors and I assure you he would never have used the word _quotidian_ had he been an English speaker. _Emphasis_ might be _Hervorhebung_ or something that could be translated differently. What work is this from?

Comment: Based on context, I would surmise that by "emphasis," the author is trying to convey the idea of shining the a spotlight on happenings, telling stories or relaying information in a manner that especially excites or shocks in order to provoke public interest and become the center of attention.

Answer (score 1):

I have problem with this sentence: If the world was dominated by emphasis, the Monarchy preferred discretion, restrained passions, a calm tone of voice.

**I can't get the first part. What is the meaning of "emphasis" here?, and What is the meaning of "If the world was [were?] dominated by emphasis"?**

---

The article seems to be a light hearted (amusing) piece of writing, where the author uses opposites to illuminate his script. As seen in the example below.

> Everything in this world was continuously in a state of constant change: familiar and strange, quotidian and remarkable,

**familiar** vs **strange**.......... **quotidian** vs **remarkable,**

Therefore it is safe to presume that emphasis is used as an opposite to

**discretion, restraint, calm**

> The **definition of EMPHASIS**, [Webster's](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/emphasis) noun In rhetoric, a particular **stress of utterance, or force of voice**, given to the words or parts of a discourse, whose signification the speaker intends to **impress specially upon his audience**

I believe the author has exercised his poetic license and modified this definition to a more general context where everything has a bold, brash, outstanding, vivid and extrovert quality. **A world, dominated by flamboyance and force of voice best suited to convey their "importance"**

---

> **flamboyance noun** [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flamboyance)
>
> the quality of being very confident in your behaviour, and liking to be noticed by other people, for example because of the way you dress or talk:.
> ​
> the quality of being very noticeable in style, colour, etc.: